# Forward client request to another server through proxy in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have two vb6 app,one is client app & other is server app,both communicates using winsock control What I want is :

what I require to do, or try is to make the server's application automatically "Port Forward" the incoming connection from Client to another Server.

Example:
Client's IP is 0.0.0.0
My IP is 1.1.1.1
Program's IP is 2.2.2.2

Normal Program Connection between Client and Program is Client will connect to program normally, and program read client's IP as 0.0.0.0

With this Serverapp, when Client (0.0.0.0) connect to My IP (1.1.1.1), My IP (Server app), will accept the connection from Client, and connect client to Program IP (2.2.2.2). So when Program read client IP, it will read as 1.1.1.1.

So how to achieve this..please post a sample code

I tried adding one more winsock control on server app & connected to the actual server,but how do I forward the client request to actual server through server app!Please post with a sample code..it will be appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QmjI.png)

Comment: Please somebody help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new code for server project:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 winsock control: name=Winsock1
'  1 textbox control: name=Text1 multiline=true scrollbars=3
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With Winsock1
    .LocalPort = 12345
    .Listen
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Text1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Close()
  With Winsock1
    Do
      If .State <> sckClosed Then
        .Close
      End If
    Loop Until .State = sckClosed
    .Listen
  End With 'Winsock1
  Text1.SelText = "Waiting for new client" & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
  With Winsock1
    If .State <> sckClosed Then
      .Close
    End If
    .Accept requestID
    Text1.SelText = "New connection from " & .RemoteHostIP & vbCrLf
  End With 'Winsock1
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
  Dim strData As String
  Winsock1.GetData strData
  If CheckHeader(strData) = False Then
    Text1.SelText = "received: " & strData & vbCrLf
  End If
End Sub

Private Function CheckHeader(strData As String) As Boolean
  Dim blnHeader As Boolean
  Dim strHeaderStart As String, strHeaderEnd As String
  Dim strHeader As String
  blnHeader = False
  strHeaderStart = "@@@"
  strHeaderEnd = "###"
  If Left$(strData, Len(strHeaderStart)) = strHeaderStart Then
    If Right$(strData, Len(strHeaderEnd)) = strHeaderEnd Then
      strHeader = Mid$(strData, Len(strHeaderStart) + 1, Len(strData) - Len(strHeaderStart) - Len(strHeaderEnd))
      Text1.SelText = "Header: " & strHeader & vbCrLf
      blnHeader = True
    End If
  End If
  CheckHeader = blnHeader
End Function
```

new code for forwarder project

```
'1 form with:
'  2 winsock controls: name=Winsock1 and name=Winsock2
'  1 textbox control: name=Text1 multiline=true scrollbars=3
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With Winsock1
    .LocalPort = 23456
    .Listen
  End With
  With Winsock2
    .Connect "laptop07", 12345
  End With 'Winsock2
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Text1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Close()
  With Winsock1
    Do
      If .State <> sckClosed Then
        .Close
      End If
    Loop Until .State = sckClosed
    .Listen
  End With 'Winsock1
  Text1.SelText = "Waiting for new client" & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
  With Winsock1
    If .State <> sckClosed Then
      .Close
    End If
    .Accept requestID
    Text1.SelText = "New connection from " & .RemoteHostIP & vbCrLf
    SendIP .RemoteHostIP
  End With 'Winsock1
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
  Dim strData As String
  Winsock1.GetData strData
  Winsock2.SendData strData
  Text1.SelText = "forwarded: " & strData & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub SendIP(strIP As String)
  Dim strHeaderStart As String, strHeaderEnd As String
  strHeaderStart = "@@@"
  strHeaderEnd = "###"
  Winsock2.SendData strHeaderStart & "IP Client:" & strIP & strHeaderEnd
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping & taking this effort.This is working

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late reply ...

a very simple and straightforward solution could be the following:

a simple server project:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 winsock control: name=Winsock1
'  1 textbox control: name=Text1 multiline=true scrollbars=3
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With Winsock1
    .LocalPort = 12345
    .Listen
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Text1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Close()
  With Winsock1
    Do
      If .State <> sckClosed Then
        .Close
      End If
    Loop Until .State = sckClosed
    .Listen
  End With 'Winsock1
  Text1.SelText = "Waiting for new client" & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
  With Winsock1
    If .State <> sckClosed Then
      .Close
    End If
    .Accept requestID
    Text1.SelText = "New connection from " & .RemoteHostIP & vbCrLf
  End With 'Winsock1
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
  Dim strData As String
  Winsock1.GetData strData
  Text1.SelText = "received: " & strData & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

a simple forwarding project:

```
'1 form with:
'  2 winsock controls: name=Winsock1 and name=Winsock2
'  1 textbox control: name=Text1 multiline=true scrollbars=3
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With Winsock1
    .LocalPort = 23456
    .Listen
  End With
  With Winsock2
    .Connect "laptop07", 12345
  End With 'Winsock2
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Text1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Close()
  With Winsock1
    Do
      If .State <> sckClosed Then
        .Close
      End If
    Loop Until .State = sckClosed
    .Listen
  End With 'Winsock1
  Text1.SelText = "Waiting for new client" & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
  With Winsock1
    If .State <> sckClosed Then
      .Close
    End If
    .Accept requestID
    Text1.SelText = "New connection from " & .RemoteHostIP & vbCrLf
  End With 'Winsock1
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
  Dim strData As String
  Winsock1.GetData strData
  Winsock2.SendData strData
  Text1.SelText = "forwarded: " & strData & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

to use first start the server, and then start the forwarder

in my example the server runs on my laptop which is known in my network as laptop07

in the code of the forwarding project replace "laptop07" with the IP address of the machine where you have the server running

the server listens on port 12345, the forwarder listens on port 23456 .. make sure they are allowed in your firewall

to test it:

- start the server
- start the forwarder
- let your client connect to the forwarder on port 23456
- send data from your client
- see it being forwarded in the forwarder
- see it being received by the server

keep in mind this is a very simple project without any error trapping

it is just to show you how it can be done

Comment: hey thanks for the code..its working,however when forwarder forwards request to server,the server only shows the client name..I want ip too.i.e. if client connects to forwarder on ip 1.1.1.1 then after forwarding client to server by forwarder it should show server ip(127.0.0.1) for eg New connection from clientname at 127.0.0.1..